# Floated divs won't expand to fit dynamic content

Tags: css, wordpress, dynamic, css-float, expand

It seems there are several posts on this topic but none of the solutions have worked for me. Perhaps someone can figure out what I'm missing.

I have three boxes floated next to each other like columns. Due to certain background images etc., each box is composed of two divs. The outer div has the class "calloutbox" and is floated left. Inside of "calloutbox" is another div called "callout-content" that holds the dynamic content (I'm using wordpress).

So far I have not been able to get the boxes to expand to fit their dynamically generated content. They collapse if I set height to 100%. I've tried a dozen combinations of overflow:hidden, clear:both etc. with no luck.

```
<div id="callout-container">
   <div class="calloutbox">
     <div class="callout-content">Dynamic content goes here</div>
   </div>
   <div class="calloutbox">
     <div class="callout-content"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="calloutbox">
     <div class="callout-content"></div>
   </div>
</div>​
```

Here is the css:

```
    .calloutbox {
    min-height:310px;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 0 25px;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(images/shadow.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right bottom;
    display:block;

}

.calloutbox:after {
    clear:both;
}

.callout-content:after {
    clear:both;
}

.calloutbox:nth-child(1) {
    min-height:200px;
}

/*The content inside the three boxes on the homepage */
.callout-content {
    height:100%;
    width:90%;
    right:8px;
    border:1px solid #e6e4e4;
    bottom: 8px;
    background-color:white;
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(images/yellow-title-bar.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:top;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}
​
```

Here's the code in a jsfiddle if that helps anyone: http://jsfiddle.net/daniec/r8ezY/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

They are not floated, they are *absolutely-positioned*.

Absolutely-positioned elements are no longer part of the layout. They no longer have parents are far as layouts are concerned. Therefore, you need to specify their sizes in pixels rather than percentages. Percentages are relative to the wrappers they no longer have.

Answer (score 1):

Working with floats can be a pain. As an alternative, have you tried using to use inline-block:

```
display: inline-block;
```

It behaves like an inline element, but an be styled like a block level element. It does not work in IE6 though.

Answer (score 0):

```
.calloutbox {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Should do the trick. otherwise try creating a jsfiddle, so we can run your code